# Neural network to learn a nonlinear function of 2 real variables

Tags: neural-networks

I am trying to build a neural network to learn a nonlinear function of 2 real variables. I have a dataset with 13000 of these vectors in 2-space and corresponding function values, and I am currently doing this on Azure ML.

How many hidden layers should I use? How many neurons? What activation function?

I have tried googling around, but I suspect that there is a particular jargon term from this task that I don't know. Thanks!

This is the data:

[image]

https://plot.ly/~housescraper/27/col1/

Comment: For these types of questions, I'd recommend consulting the Neural Network FAQ. ftp://ftp.sas.com/pub/neural/FAQ.html

Comment: Actually, if it's just a function of two variables, why not just fit a Gaussian process? It will avoid so many headaches that come with neural networks, and will have so many fewer knobs to worry about turning!

Comment: @user777: Can you point me in the to some kind of introduction to "fitting a Gaussian process"? BTW neither of my variables are time. It is not clear to me that a Gaussian process is what I need, but I defer to the judgement of those who know more about stats than I do...

Comment: Guassian processes can be used for time-dependent data, but are by no means restricted to it. For example, imagine you're interested in knowing the topography of a lakebed. It's possible to build an approximation of it using soundings of the depth via GP -- or, in general, any function of several variables where you expect the function value to be similar in some neighborhood. *Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning* is a good start. *Bayesian Data Analysis* 3rd ed also has a chapter.

Comment: Yup, I'd definitely use a GP for this: spatially arranged data with a continuous outcome. Totally a use case for a GP. But I initially misread the size of your data: 13k data points is a lot to fit a GP. So you'll either need to make do with a smaller subset (probably possible to build a good model with smaller data) or look into methods with sparsity properties like support vector regression.

Comment: @user777: so are NNs just incapable of learning this? What is it about this data that prevents a NN from learning it?

BTW decision forests already get something out of this data, but I wanted to attack the problem from multiple angles. I didn't consider support vector regression. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't say ANNs were ineffective, I said that there are a ton of headaches that come along with ANNs: number of hidden layers, number of nodes, choice of activation function, and all of the indeterminacies of parameter estimation and all of the alternative regularization methods. That's a lot of choices. But please, by all means, do what you think is best -- it's your project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31369/discussion-between-rationalist-and-user777).

Comment: @Rationalist The term you are looking for is "grid search". In addition, MacKay has a nice introduction to neural nets. If you need something simpler in terms of expressions, have a look at Hagan.

Answer (score 1):

> How many hidden layers should I use? How many neurons?

In your scenario you have two inputs neurons and one output neuron. Hidden layers are a hyperparamether of the neural networks and the ultimate answer is by trial and error. I would start with 1 hidden layer with two neurons and grow from there by making the network deeper.

> What activation function?

Start simple with a sigmoid function. I also suggest to normalise input and output in [-1, 1]. This is what Haykin, S. (2008). Neural Networks and Learning Machines suggests at page 146 of his book.

Each time you iterate over your hyperparams check the performace of your prediction using some form of validation (Cross Validation over mean squared error) and iterate again

Comment: I have been messing around with it since I asked, and taking the log of the values and predicting that actually produced some learning.

Scaling the unlogged values seems to make no difference - it just doesn't learn anything at all.

Comment: how about discretizing the input? maybe this will reduce the complexity a bit. Also I suspect that 13000 examples may not be enough. Have you tried to see what happens if you produce more examples by simply duplicating them (possibly with a tiny bit of noise to differentiate)?